# How to list files in a directory on cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I saved files on the writable directory of iPhone simulator.
The files can be removed and created dynamically in run time.
I want to list these files in the specific directory by using directory path, not filename.

Example:

```
/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/022F7891-1983-4791-AB59-451B2EAF4FB8/Documents/stage/stage_1.json
/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/022F7891-1983-4791-AB59-451B2EAF4FB8/Documents/stage/stage_2.json
/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/022F7891-1983-4791-AB59-451B2EAF4FB8/Documents/stage/stage_24.json
/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/022F7891-1983-4791-AB59-451B2EAF4FB8/Documents/stage/stage_3.json
/Users/mine/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/022F7891-1983-4791-AB59-451B2EAF4FB8/Documents/stage/stage_4.bmp
```

> vector = getFilesInDir(FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath()+string("Documents/stage"), "json");
>
> vector => ("stage_1.json", "stage_1.json", "stage_1.json", "stage_1.json")

Comment: then prepend FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath()+string("Documents/stage/") to every string in the vector

Comment: to add to what @LearnCocos2D said, `getWritablePath()` will return the right location on the platform you are running on. iOS, android, windows, etc.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : No need to append `Documents` in path because `getWriteablePath()` method already append it to path. See here https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/cocos2d-x-3.2/cocos/platform/apple/CCFileUtilsApple.mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross platform API in cocos2dx for listing directory contents. You can store file names in an array while creating them.

If you want to read files by just their names then you need to insert folder path to search path to search path in `CCFileUtils`

```
FileUtils *fileUtils = FileUtils::getInstance();
vector<string> searchPaths = fileUtils->getSearchPaths();
string path = fileUtils->getWritablePath() + "stage";
searchPaths.insert(searchPaths.begin(), path);
fileUtils->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```